# «не смогла доказать, что ее(?) ассистент фактически выполняла ее(?) обязанности»

Tags: семантика, местоимения

Попалась фраза на глаза - и ввергла в некоторый ступор, из которого я не сразу вышел.

> Cуд пришел к мнению, что Ле Пен «не смогла доказать, что ее ассистент
>   фактически выполняла ее обязанности».

(Из сети).

Ну понятно, что это перевод, горячий, но сыроватый, вернее всего - с английского. Причем в английском - там та же омонимия личного и притяжательного местоимения (her). Но в переводе явная двусмысленность, ибо эти два "её" по логике относятся к разным персонам, а по грамматике - к одной. В результате - что-то непонятное. Или я придираюсь?!

Надо ли было править - и как?!

UPD
"Как" - снимаю.  Вариант "свои" очевиден, это я тормознул. Остается "надо ли"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что Вы правы, местоимение "свои" будет на месте:

*Cуд пришел к мнению, что Ле Пен «не смогла доказать, что ее ассистент фактически (а не только на словах) выполняла свои обязанности»* ,   т.е. на самом деле, а не фиктивно работала в Европарламенте. А вот второе  "её" допускает двусмысленность, можно подумать, что она выполняла обязанности Ле Пен, о чём речь не идёт.

Comment: Людмила, спасибо. Я правильно понимаю, что замена на "свои" обезательна, или это мягкая рекомендация?!

Comment: Классическая речевая ошибка, замена обязательна для уважающего себя журналиста, но у нас сейчас в моде "ляпы", даже дикторы косноязычны, я уже не удивляюсь. Студентам в вузах дают задание: найдите ошибки в газетах и журналах. Это уж ни в какие ворота. Примета времени.

Comment: Людмила, спасибо. Только это не совсем "у нас". Это с украинского сайта. ))) Так что про "дикторов" - не по адресу. Там у них вообще с русским в СМИ - чудеса и леший бродит. Все это добавляет новых красок в тамошний  языковый вопрос. Кабы не требование избегать политизации ресурса, я таких бы перлов сюда накидал...

Comment: "Фактически" (= "практически") в русском - не слишком определённое слово, с первого прочтения и без контекста даже непонятно, о чём идёт речь (можно подумать: "занималась именно тем, что нужно", в то время как речь идёт о "присутствии на рабочем месте"), Я бы заменил его здесь на "**действительно** (выполняла свои)". Если нужна юридическая строгость, то лучше "де-факто".

Comment: Согласна. Но если сайт украинский - всё нормально, для них русский неродной, неудивительно. что "фактически " воспринимается как точный синоним к "действительно" (по факту).